# Editable ComboBox Open Select File Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a ComboBox with 3 options:

- off
- auto
- select

`off` and `auto` are normal items, but `select` changes the ComboBox to `editable` and opens a `Select File` dialog box.

But when I press ok, the selected file will not appear in the ComboBox editable textbox using `myComboBox.Text = selectFile.FileName`.

How do I get the text to appear in the textbox?

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" 
          Margin="0,164,14,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          Width="103" 
          IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
          SelectionChanged="myComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <System:String>off</System:String>
    <System:String>auto</System:String>
    <System:String>select</System:String>
</ComboBox>
```

**C#**

```
private void myComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)myComboBox.SelectedItem == "select")
    {
        myComboBox.IsEditable = true;

        // Open 'Select File'
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog selectFile = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        selectFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
        Nullable<bool> result = selectFile.ShowDialog();

        // Process dialog box
        if (result == true)
        {
            myComboBox.Text = selectFile.FileName;
        }
    }

    else if ((string)myComboBox.SelectedItem != "select" 
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)myComboBox.SelectedItem))
    {
        myComboBox.IsEditable = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select an item in the combobox that is not one of the items in the list for the combobox.  So to accomplish what you want you need to add the selected file to list of items and then select it.  Like so...

```
            // Process dialog box
            if (result == true)
            {
                myComboBox.Items.Add(selectFile.FileName);
                myComboBox.SelectedItem = selectFile.FileName;
            }
```

Comment: Though I am just selecting the item called "select" and then it changes to an empty textbox that you can type in. I'd like the empty textbox to be filled with the `selectFile.Filename`.

Comment: Yes.  The "SelectedItem" statement accomplishes that.

Comment: I will probably use this method, but I'd like to avoid adding another option to the combobox, I want to see if there are other answers.

Comment: There is no other answer for the question you have proposed.  I think what you really want is a hidden textbox that appears only when the select item is selected.  You are asking the combobox to do too much.